# Angular 4 - DateFormatter - how to

Tags: angular, internationalization, formatdatetime

I have application in Angular 2 that use custom formatting date to Polish:

```
return DateFormatter.format( new Date( date + ' 12:00:00' ), 'pl-PL', 'd MMMM y' );
```

It is possible by importing class

```
import { DateFormatter } from '@angular/common/src/facade/intl';
```

Next, I converting/upgrading my application to Angular 4.3 and this class (DateFormatter) is no longer there.

I someone knows where it is located, or what other methods I should use to achieve such formatting?

Answer (score 1):

The `DateFormatter` class can currently be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/54e02449549448ebab6f255f2da0b4396665c6f0/packages/common/src/pipes/intl.ts#L222) in source code.

However, Angular disallows importing from deep path such as this one. If `@angular/common` does not expose the function you're looking for, it means it's private and you're not supposed to be using it (which is why your application broke after upgrading).

Consider using the [`DatePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) or a utility library such as [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/).

Answer (score 0):

In our application we use [date pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe). E.g. `<p class="dIB">{{bfPreventer.nextControlDate | date: 'shortDate'}}</p>`

By default it takes the current culture of your browser. But you can change it at start up. I'm not sure if it's perfect, but it works for us well.

```
@NgModule({
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
declarations: [
    ...pageComponents
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...
    TranslateModule.forRoot(),

],
providers: [

    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: window.navigator.language.indexOf("en") >= 0 ? "en-US" : "nb-NO" },

]})
```

Also, please take into the consideration that the pipe relies on i18n API of the browser, so old browsers might have issues with that.